# Can Google App Engine be used with phonegap apps?

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine, cordova

I have been developing Phonegap application. I was looking into how Google App Engine(GAE) can be used with Phonegap.

I have couple of queries for which I couldn't find explanation after I Googled a little bit..

- How GAE can be used with Phonegap?
- Can GAE be used with existing Phonegap apps?
- How is it beneficial?
- What will be pros and cons?

I Googled little bit but .

Any links to give overview of this would be a great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google app engine with your phonegap using custom web service (REST and SOAP) as long your app can request and response with your web service.